# Не удается менять данные в бд Sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, sqlite3

у меня есть два файла один файл это бот, второй файл для работы с бд

Файл для работы с бд:

```
import sqlite3

class SQLighter:

    def __init__(self, database):
        """Подключаемся к БД и сохраняем курсор соединения"""
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def subscriber_exists(self, id):
        """Проверяем, есть ли уже юзер в базе"""
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `id` = ?', (id,)).fetchall()
            print(result)
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_subscriber(self, id):
        """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `accounts` VALUES(?)", (id,))
            self.connection.commit()
```

файл с ботом:

```
from database import SQLighter
db = SQLighter('db.db')

id = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['from_id']
body = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['text']

if body == 'Начать':
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(id)):
        db.add_subscriber(id)
        vk_session.method
```

Код доходит до проверки idшников, но результат уже не приходит. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: проверил ваш код, вызвав `db.add_subscriber(id)`. Записи нормально добавляются...

Comment: Что со мной не так?..

Comment: с такими вопросами - это не ко мне! :-D

Comment: Я даже пробовал на другой ОС, все тот же результат

Comment: вы уверены, что условие `if body == 'Начать'` срабатывает?

Comment: Уверен, я добавлял функцию print() после условия, она срабатывает

Comment: если вы уверены, что функция `db.add_subscriber(id)`вызывается и новые `id` при этом не добавляются, то для этого есть лишь одно объяснение - у вас как минимум два файла `db.db` и скрипт пишет в один файл, а вы проверяете другой. Чтобы избежать подобных проблем используйте __полные пути__ к файлам

Comment: действительно, сейчас исправлю и отпишусь

Comment: Все проверил, указал полный путь до файла бд, скрипт останавливается на функции subscriber_exists(id) и после запроса к бд, для проверки id останавливается